# Trying to print Json key values but indexes are getting printed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The expected output should print the keys and its values

```
var myData = '{"is_bot":"No","device":"desktop","brand":"Sony","brand_model":"Vaio","os":"GNU\/Linux","os_version":"15.5","browser":"Chrome","browser_version":"52.0","ua_string":"Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/52.0.2743.82 Safari\/537.36"}'
    for (var key in myData) {
       console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + myData[key]);
    }
```

However the console is printing

[image: Console Output]

Help is appreciated

Comment: You are defining myData as a string
var myData = '{ ... }'
must be
var myData = { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string as JSON first using `JSON.parse(str)`

```js
var myData = '{"is_bot":"No","device":"desktop","brand":"Sony","brand_model":"Vaio","os":"GNU\/Linux","os_version":"15.5","browser":"Chrome","browser_version":"52.0","ua_string":"Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/52.0.2743.82 Safari\/537.36"}';

   myData = JSON.parse(myData);

    for (var key in myData) {
       console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + myData[key]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. All of your solutions worked. Basically I wasn't parsing the json data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your string into actual javascript objects. The results you're seeing are because you're iterating over a string.

```js
var raw = '{"is_bot":"No","device":"desktop","brand":"Sony","brand_model":"Vaio","os":"GNU\/Linux","os_version":"15.5","browser":"Chrome","browser_version":"52.0","ua_string":"Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/52.0.2743.82 Safari\/537.36"}';

var data = JSON.parse(raw);

for (var key in data) {
    console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the key is reading the JSON as a string - you need to remove the single quotes `'` from it to make it an Ojbect

like so:

```
var myData = {"is_bot":"No","device":"desktop","brand":"Sony","brand_model":"Vaio","os":"GNU\/Linux","os_version":"15.5","browser":"Chrome","browser_version":"52.0","ua_string":"Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/52.0.2743.82 Safari\/537.36"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over each char in your string, as this is a string and not an object.

```
 var myData = JSON.parse(myData);

 Object.keys(myData).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(' name=' + key + ' value=' + myData[key]); 
 });
```

For more information about `Object.keys` please check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)